# Does Ember.js have an opinion when it comes to managing sets of views ( and models )?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am looking to do some granular control on what happens to each view based on user interaction. In addition, what happens to each view also depends on what other views are currently doing, thus the need to keep all views in one array. Based on the simple examples I find online, the controller seems to be intended to manage sets of models? Currently, I am extending the concept to views by have a 'viewController' of sort. This solution doesn't appear egregious to me although I am not really sure.

Please note though, this appears to be a very general question since there's no one right answer, and what is right is different in each case. However, keeping in mind of Ember's opinionated ways, I am simply asking if the people making Ember had one particular way in mind that I have yet been clued to, and build Ember so that this 'one way' has the most functionalities.

Comment: Ember guides provide a pretty thorough explanation about management of views: http://emberjs.com/guides/view_layer/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The primary responsibility of controllers in Ember apps are to present data to the view to render.

A good solution for managing dynamic collections of views is to subclass `Ember.ContainerView` and have it update it's `childViews` property in response to properties changing on the controller. You can look at the source code for `Ember.CollectionView` for an example.

I did a talk where I've laid out the responsibilities of the various classes of objects in Ember apps and how they work together. You can check it out here: http://www.lukemelia.com/blog/archives/2012/08/23/architecting-ember-js-apps/

Comment: Also, towards the other slides suggests models should be a layer that cannot be accessed by others except by the router. Thus, when the powerpoint says 'router updates model based on events,' does it mean the router should be updating the model's fields? Thus the router has more functionality than just defining the states and the transition among them?

Comment: Yes, the router is responsible for handling app-level events/actions appropriately for the current state of the application. That often includes transitioning to another state, but can also include manipulating models or controllers.